# Название пакета при публикации в PlayMarket

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, playmarket

Пытаюсь залить бета-версию на маркет: пишет нельзя использовать в названии пакета "com.example.". Поменял название. Теперь пишет что наоборот должно присутствовать в названии "com...". Как правильно назвать приложение для маркета? 
Подписи сделал для release версии.

Выдаёт такую ошибку:

> Название пакета APK должно иметь формат com.example.prilozhenie. Оно
>   может содержать буквы (a-z), цифры и символ подчеркивания (_).
>   Название должно начинаться со строчной буквы, а его длина не может
>   превышать 150 симв

.

Comment: `com.example.` да, нелья. Всё остальное валидное - можно. Уточните ошибку. Пакет и подпись должны у беты совпадать с релизом.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Не понятно. Зачем путают.

Comment: Релиз ещё не заливал.

Comment: Ну, видимо у вас пакет невалидный. Покажите его. Ну или хоть часть, если он секретный

Comment: Возможно это из-за того, что второй раз я заливал подписанную (с изменённым названием) копию первого проэкта.

Comment: Возможно. Проверьте, что у вас везде пакеты и подписи совпадают.

Comment: В общем на свежую голову с утра получилось. Было две проблемы: 1. Имя пакета пошло только в виде com.prilozheniename. 2. Готовый релиз я брал из папки \app\release, а он лежал в \app\build\outputs\apk\release. Ну и конечно package name и applicationId должны совпадать (хотя где-то я читал что они могут быть разными ).

Comment: Вы можете написать это в ответ)

Comment: .............Ок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Имя пакета пошло только в виде com.prilozhenie. 2. Готовый релиз я брал из папки \app\release, а он лежал в \app\build\outputs\apk\release. Ну и конечно package name и applicationId должны совпадать (хотя где-то я читал что они могут быть разными ). Для подписи релиза лучше использовать встроенные средства Android Studio и не заморачиваться коммандной строкой, т.к. начинающие легко могут запутаться.

Answer (score 0):

Название пакета должен соответствовать названием пакета. Можно назвать по другому но это взависомости от функционал приложение. Например у вас называется приложение NewProject а имя разработчика/фирмы Tester. Тогда идентификатор должен называтся com.tester.newproject

Comment: Может быть и так. Я не штампую приложения каждый день, так что проверить это пока не смогу)